# NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have these problem when I try to save my model. Besides, I am using Tensorflow 2.0.0 and numpy 1.6.0, so I don't know how to solve the problem because in the latest versions of tensorflow, the eager execution is enabled by default.

```
Compilamos
Entrenamos
Train on 946 samples, validate on 237 samples
Epoch 1/2
946/946 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6866 - accuracy: 0.5719 - val_loss: 0.6897 - val_accuracy: 0.5316
Epoch 2/2
946/946 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.6782 - accuracy: 0.5729 - val_loss: 0.6862 - val_accuracy: 0.5316
Entrenamiento finalizado
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-35267c139307>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Narcis Teodoroiu/Desktop/Version MASK R-CNN/TILErecognitionYcant.py', wdir='C:/Users/Narcis Teodoroiu/Desktop/Version MASK R-CNN')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Narcis Teodoroiu/Desktop/Version MASK R-CNN/TILErecognitionYcant.py", line 332, in <module>
    model.save('tile_cnn_model.h5')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1152, in save
    save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 449, in save_wrapper
    save_function(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 541, in save_model
    _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 179, in _serialize_model
    'config': model.optimizer.get_config()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 557, in get_config
    config = {'learning_rate': float(K.get_value(self.learning_rate)),

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2927, in get_value
    return x.numpy()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 579, in numpy
    "numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.")

NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.
```

Comment: Pls add a working example. But based on the error code i suggest, that you call `tf.Tensor().numpy()` in a static graph. Try to delete the `.numpy`

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue when try to migrate my project from "tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0" to "tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0", and this error was solved when I enabled tensorflow v2 functions (I disabled v2 functions at first).

If you disabled "tf_v2" function before, maybe you can try to comment it out.

> # tf.disable_v2_behavior()

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue when upgrade to TensorFlow V2.0. 
And it was solved by commenting out
`#from keras import backend as K`. 
And use 
`import tensorflow.keras.backend as K`

Comment: Thanks! this solution works for me. I just disabled the line and restarted the notebook and it produced the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was caused by the `tensorflow_addons` module, since it was using `sefl.numpy` on `0.14` somewhere under the hood. To fix that you have to upgrade `tensorflow_addons` to `0.16.0` or above.

To install `tensorflow-addons` use command:

`pip install tensorflow-addons==0.16.1`

**Keep in your mind that you need `python 3.7` and above.**