# Error loading saved model with Keras in TensorFlow 1.x: "NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled"

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, hdf5

I want to run this repo (https://github.com/hfawaz/ijcnn19attacks/blob/master/src/cleverhans_tutorials/tsc_tutorial_keras_tf.py) In line 186 it tries to load a saved ML model

```
        model = keras.models.load_model(file_path)
```

I cloned the repository and make two small changes for compatibility with tensorflow.compat.v1

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Then everything is ok and I can lunch the program loading its saved model ( [The file Adiac1.hdf5](https://easyupload.io/m/943rau) )

After that I tried to make the saved model myself and the result was [the file Adiac2.hdf5](https://easyupload.io/m/943rau) But when I want to run the program the line

```
        model = keras.models.load_model(file_path)
```

rais the following error:

> NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is
> enabled.

what is the reason for the difference in loading two files?
As I can see apparently in some cases, when using the Keras library's load_model function to load a saved model, it may be necessary to enable eager execution mode in order to properly load and use the model. However, in other cases, enabling eager execution mode may not be necessary or even desirable. why?

Comment: Useful answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816662/notimplementederror-numpy-is-only-available-when-eager-execution-is-enabled

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the mentioned solutions. The problem is disabling tf v2 behavior is needed for other parts of the code  but make  problem with this part (model loading)
@nithish08

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was a version conflict between some libraries.
I changed my requirement.txt and libraries and finally, the problem was handled!

```
keras = 2.10.0
numpy = 1.24.2
pandas = 1.3.5
scikit-learn = 1.0.2
scipy = 1.7.3
matplotlib = 3.6.2
tensorflow-gpu = 2.10.1
h5py = 3.7.0
```